# How to I loop through this json response in php and perform an action after each loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
$response='{"Data":[{"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"},
{"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"},
{"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"}
```

This is my JSON response. How do I loop through the values?

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```
$array = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    echo $val; 
}
```

Comment: thanks @vamsi but getting this error<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in

Comment: The json is multidimensional. This answer is just for flat json/arrays

Answer (score 1):

There is an error on your JSON string

```
 <?php

 $response='{"Data":
 [{"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"},
 {"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"},
 {"item_name":"FL001(1)","Qty":"50","color":"red","Rate":"50","Amt":"2500"}]}';
                                //this two closing brackets you are missing^^

$parsed = json_decode($response, true);

$what_you_need = $parsed["Data"];

//example output with a loop
foreach($what_you_need as $key=> $value){
  echo "key: ".$key  //key
     . ", item_name: ".$value["item_name"]."</br>"  //item name + a linebreak
     ."Qty: ".$value["Qyt"]  //Qyt value
     .", color: ".$value["color"]  //color
     .", Rate: ".$value["Rate"]    //rate
     .", Amt: ".$value["Amt"]."</br></hr>";  //Amt + linebreak and header row
}
```